Writing a string to the screen fails in VGA graphical mode but writing a char succeeds
I am guessing i am making a relatively simple mistake however I cannot figure out why a character can be written but a string cannot.
This is my graphics code in c:
void put_pixel(int pos_x, int pos_y, int VGA_COLOR)
{
    unsigned char* location = (unsigned char*)0xA0000 + 320 * pos_y + pos_x;
    *location = VGA_COLOR;
}

void put_char(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int fgcolor) {
    unsigned char* font = (unsigned char*)0x80000;
    int cx, cy;
    unsigned char *glyph = font + (int)c * 16;
    for (cy = 0; cy < 16; cy++) {
        for (cx = 0; cx < 8; cx++) {
            if (glyph[cy] & (1 << (7 - cx))) {
                put_pixel(x + cx, y + cy, fgcolor);
            }
        }
    }
}

void put_string(char* s, int x, int y, int fgcolor){
    for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++){
        put_char(s[i], (i+x)*8, y, 0x000f);
    }
}

This is how I am running it:
#include "helper/screen.c"

void main(){
    put_char('h', 0, 0, 0x000f); // Works
    put_string("hello world", 0, 0, 0x000f); // Does not work
}

This is my bootloader code for changing the graphics mode:
mov ah, 0x00
mov al, 0x13
int 0x10

This is my font code:
[bits 16]
load_font:
    mov ax, 0x8000
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x0
    mov di, ax
    push ds
    push es
    mov ax, 1130h
    mov bh, 6
    int 10h
    push es
    pop ds
    pop es
    mov si, bp
    mov cx, 256*16/4
    rep movsd
    pop ds
    ret

I tried multiple different loops to get it working however nothing worked. Writing a singular character works. This is running in 32-bit protected mode and the font is whatever the default font used by the vga card is.

You're writing all characters at position (10,10). You need something like put_char(s[i], x+i, y, (unsigned char)0x000f);

Yes i have tried this. In my question description i had used that position because no characters are being displayed at all its not that they are just on top of each other

Does put_char('b', 10, 10, 15); put_char('a', 18, 10, 15); put_char('r', 26, 10, 15); work? I assume it does ... and you have some kind of UB somewhere.

No because the last argument is the color which should be a VGA color hex casted to an unsigned char

Too many casts (which you have) are bad. The compiler will correctly convert automatically in most situations ... or warn you of a wrong argument. When you cast you silence the (helpful) warnings! Make sure you have the proper includes in place! Pay attention to the warnings (maybe treat warnings as errors?)

Ok i have removed all of the useless unsigned char casts but the string print function still does nothing

Please add a complete [mre] to the question, as on here posts have to be self contained. You can still link to external resources for further details but everything necessary has to be contained within the post.

The answer was as simple as i had expected. I needed to be passing a char[] to the function not a char literal;

@AlexOT : Are you sure your kernel hasn't now exceeded 2 sectors and part of your kernel is not being read into memory? As I recall somewhere in your code you read a maximum of 2 sectors in load_kernel. If your kernel binary (kernel.bin) is larger than 1024 you could run into problems like this. Passing a char * or char [] to put_string should work. My guess is when you use char * the string is in an .rodata section and that section with the string is beyond the limit of the 2 sectors being read. This is just a guess.

Note: I suspect that using the "hello world" as a parameter to put_string made the compiler generate an .rodata section in your kernel. Because you don't supply your own linker script it probably defaulted to page alignment and your kernel.bin exploded in size from less than 1024 to over 4096. The string isn't being loaded into memory so when you go to print it, it shows nothing.

You may ask why something like char str[]="hello world"; put_string(str, 0, 0, 0x000f); appears to work. This is because for small strings the string is built on the stack at run time so the string isn't in a new .rodata section. I say appears to work because most compilers with longer strings will eventually realize creating an .rodata section and doing a memory copy from .rodata to the stack is more efficient. The thing you need to fix is to always read enough sectors to load your entire kernel.
